# Suitable Data type for Name Value Pair

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I want to store Name Value pairs in my class. I tried the following and end up with following issues;

1. Use `NameValeCollection` : This was not success. Because I want to bind this Collection to a `DataTemplate` as `ItemsSource`. I was success in binding **Name** but not for the **Value** in the collection.

**Template and XAML**

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="MyCollectionTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <TextBox Name="CValue" Text="{Binding Path=Value}"/> //did not work this binding
    </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>     

 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"  x:Name="MyCollectionControl" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource MyCollectionTemplate}" />
```

`MyCollection` is the `NameValueCollection.`

1. Use `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` : In this case I was success in binding key value pair. But unfortunately that supports only for `OneWay` Binding. So I cannot use that as well.

Please suggest me a way to handle this. I cannot use `Dictionary` as well. Because in the Name Value Pair Key is not unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you just create your own custom class? i.e.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then just have a list, or observable collection of that class.

```
ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyCollection
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Note that if your collections values are likely to change, you will need to implement INotifyProperyChanged in MyClass.

Answer (score 1):

For the collection, i would suggest using an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx).

The Name/Value pair sounds simple, so if you want change notifications on both name and value of that pair, you could implement a class with those two properties and change notification (e.g. via [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)) yourself and use that in your collection.

You can find an example on how to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your class here:
[How to: Implement Property Change Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)

If you do both of these, you will get change notifications on the addition and removal of name/value pairs and `TwoWay` binding on name/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/system.tuple.aspx).

Like

```
Tuple<string,string> t = Tuple.Create("key", "value");
string key = t.Item1;
string value = t.Item2;
```